# File Download over http request failed

Tags: android, download, httprequest

In My android Application i have a list of song.User can download any of song from it.
But my problem is when i download a file using http request it return content length = 0 or -1 so i can not download file.
When i use same url in browser then song downloaded completely.
My code to download a song file is -

```
  URL url = new URL(mUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(TimeOut);
                connection.setReadTimeout(TimeOut);
                connection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
```

and file length is either 0 or -1.
What the problem in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the extension of your songs files ?

Comment: The server did not send that info. Just open a stream and start to read().

Comment: @Nadir i have different different file extension like aac.m4a,avf.mp3

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run an Http Request wheter download or upload is to use AsycTask in order to split the download task from your UI,

try to download your file by putting this code in a method and call it, if your using an AsyncTask you can add a progressBar and update it's progression from the below given code

to update progress uncomment

```
   updateProgress(downloadedSize,totalSize);

  try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL("File Url");

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"song.extension");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize); if your run this code from AsyncTask

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

//catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i use your code it gives bufferLength -1 in line  - while ( (bufferLength = input.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {